# What's the different between browserHistory.push() and location.replace()

Tags: location, browser-history

I build my project with react, when I want to change the URL I find both browserHistory.push(myUrl) and location.replace() are worked. So I want to know what's the different between them.

```
divClick() {
    location.replace('/doctor/task');
    // browserHistory.push('/doctor/task');
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={this.divClick.bind(this)}>Change</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**History Push**
The user can go forward and backward in the browser and the url will change. It works like a programmatic link with no affect on current url.

**Location Replace**
The link of the page is set to the new one, but the user can't go between the replaced.

Hope this will help you ;)